# Simple way to turn array of objects into object with grouped keys as arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I am looking for a simple way to do the following. I have tried to do this with `lodash.reduce` and it is clunky, is there an easier way.

From:

```
[{a: 'meow'}, {a: 'woof'}]
```

To:

```
{a: ['meow', 'woof']}
```

Comment: Care to share the effort? A user with your rep should know the importance of it

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with pure JS, no need of loadash.

Call the `reduce` method of arrays on your input array, and reduce the array to an object, looping over the keys of your inner objs:

```js
const input = [{a: 'meow'}, {a: 'woof'}, {b: 'hi'}, {a: 'dog', c: 'bye'}, {}];

console.log(input.reduce((acc, val) => {
  Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
    if(!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(val[key]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

Comment: I have added more objects to the input set, just to show this works over a generalized set. +1. You can rollback if you dislike this change. I apologize in that case

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**lodash#assignWith**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assignWith) to assign all properties their respective values into one object, together with a customizer function to determine how you want to structure the object.

```
const result = _.assignWith({}, ...data, (v = [], s) => v.concat(s));
```

Note: To make sure that we don't mutate any of the objects in the `data` array, I passed an empty object as the first parameter to act as the destination object.

```js
const data = [
  { a: 'meow' },
  { a: 'woof', k: 'hey' },
  { k: 'yo', d: 'hehe' },
  { d: 'wazup', q: 'ohoho' }
];

const result = _.assignWith({}, ...data, (v = [], s) => v.concat(s));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: also, `_.mergeWith` can be used for the same

Comment: Since the OP's situation doesn't deal with recursively assigning values, then I simply opted to use `lodash#assignWith`

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with typescript and lodash.reduce, this worked.

```
export function getFuncsObject(funcs): Record<Funcs, Case[]> {
  let f = { ...funcs };
  f = lodash.mapValues(f, () => []);
  return f;
}

export function mockMerge(funcs, mocks: Record<Funcs, Case | null>[]): Record<Funcs, Case[]> {
  const f = getFuncsObject(funcs);
  lodash.each(mocks, (v, k) => {
    f[k].push(v);
  });
  return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use two reductions as follows:

```js
const input = [{
  a: 'meow'
}, {
  a: 'woof'
}, {
  b: 'moo'
}];

const result = input
.reduce((itemResult, item) => Object.keys(item)
.reduce((keyResult, key) => ({
  ...keyResult,
  [key]: (keyResult[key] || []).concat(item[key])
}), itemResult), {});

console.log(result)
```

Not sure if this is clunky compared to your current solution, but it's fairly concise and does not require an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external libraries or reduce.

```js
const input = [ {a: 'meow'}, {a: 'woof'}, {b: 'hi'}, {a: 'dog', c: 'bye'}, {} ];
let output = {};

input.forEach((inputObj) => {
  for(let key in inputObj){
    if(!output[ key ]){
      output[ key ] = [];
    }
    output[ key ].push(inputObj[key])
  }
});


console.log(output);
```